# Custom thumbnail to click autoplay from Youtube doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have embed youtube, the idea is to set my own image and when I click the image, it's autoplay the video.
But when I click the image, instead playing the video, it shows me the youtube button and I need to click once again to play the video, I tried to use the suggestion from other people to add: ?autoplay=1;

However, it doesn't work, please advice.

```html
<div onclick="this.nextElementSibling.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'">
        <img src="img" style="cursor:pointer">
</div>

    <div style="display:none">
        <iframe
                width="560"
                height="315"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/IxXO2ybSvfg"
                frameborder="0"
                allow="accelerometer;
                ?autoplay=1;
                encrypted-media;
                gyroscope;
                picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what Firefox displays in Web Console:
Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name "autoplay".